# Java Apache Spark Maven Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I'm new to Maven, I'm trying to use it to build an Apache Spark project, on VSCode.

I've followed that guide to create my project:
[maven.apache](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html).

And I've been trying to follow [that video](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) on Youtube.

When I try to run my code:

## App.java

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try {
            File test = new File("test/test.csv");
            Scanner testReader = new Scanner(test);
            testReader.close();
            System.out.println("Will it work ?");

            SparkConf confederation = new SparkConf();

            System.out.println("Did it work ?");

          } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

## pom.xml

I have added this in my pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

## Output

When I do `$ mvn package`  everything seems fine, but when I
run  `java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App`

I get:

```
(base) ➜  my-app java -cp target/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.app.App

Will it work?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/SparkConf
        at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.SparkConf
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
        ... 1 more
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You were not too far off. You can refer to this example: https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch01 and more specifically its [pom.xml](https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch01/blob/master/pom.xml). It is not yet with Spark 3.2 & Scala 2.13, but you will get the gist of it.

In essence, Apache Spark needs several modules and you just included one. I also remove logging stuff from Spark, it is probably not needed anymore, but they were in earlier Spark built and could have created some confusion. This is how I structure mines:

```
  <properties>
    <scala.version>2.12</scala.version>
    <spark.version>3.1.2</spark.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- Spark -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-mllib_${scala.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I always use properties as you want to ensure the same version of Spark and Scala across all your dependencies.

Alternatively, I also use the exec plugin, so you do not have to use those pesky complex Java command line and you can see `mvn exec:exec`. To do so, add:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <executable>java</executable>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-classpath</argument>
        <classpath />
        <argument>net.jgp.books.spark.ch01.lab100_csv_to_dataframe.CsvToDataframeApp</argument>
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Do these work without scala?